# Is there a way to have VPNC failover automatically to a second Cisco firewall?

Tags: ipsec, cisco-vpn, cisco-pix, vpn

I'm currently using VPNC on my Ubuntu machine to VPN to a remote Cisco firelwall. It's critical for this VPN connection to be up at all time.

Is there a way to have VPNC failover automatically to a second Cisco firewall in case the main firewall goes down for some reason?